# putting (aux log out toc bbl bib blg) files in another directory with latexmk

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, auxiliary-files

Is it possible to put (aux log out toc bbl bib blg) files in another directory with latexmk?

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30350/use-miktex-option-through-latexmk

Comment: Jonas' solution, which is based on a more current version of latexmk, seems superior to me; I suggest changing the accepted answer.

Comment: @doncherry: Done, but it doesn't yet work with my MacTex installation unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`auxdir` is the directory for all auxiliary files **but not the PDF** file.

`latexmk -auxdir=/tmp test.tex` should work. You can extend this to autocompile with `latexmk -auxdir=/tmp -pdf -pvc test.tex`

The manual `man latexmk` / [`texdoc latexmk`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/latexmk) explains more about the `auxdir` parameter:

> ```
> -auxdir=FOO or -aux-directory=FOO
>
>           Sets the directory for  auxiliary  output  files  of  (pdf)latex
>           (.aux,  .log  etc).  This achieves its effect by the -aux-direc‐
>           tory option of (pdf)latex, which currently is  only  implemented
>           on the MiKTeX version of (pdf)latex.
>
>           See   also   the   -outdir/-output-directory  options,  and  the
>           $aux_dir,  $out_dir,  and  $search_path_separator  configuration
>           variables  of  latexmk.  In particular, see the documentation of
>           $out_dir for some complications  on  what  directory  names  are
>           suitable.
> ```

The auxdir parameter was introduced in [version 4.39](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//software/latexmk-jcc/versions.html).

Comment: Which versions of `latexmk` have this feature? I'm on 4.24, and it doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: @dinosaur V. 4.24 was released in May 2011, the auxdir was introduced in 2013.

Comment: for texlive, you will need to `emulate_aux`

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that `latexmk` also can handle the option `output-directory=...`

Comment: can I keep the pdf file in the same directory, or is that too hard?

Comment: I got output-directory working by changing the way latexmk calls pdflatex

Comment: no, _all_ output is affected. I always put a link from my doc directory to the pdf in the outpunt directory.

Comment: good idea.

Comment: I think that you might have to use `-jobname` with recent versions of `latexmk`. (My version does not seem to support the output-directory option.)

Comment: `\jobname` has nothing to do with the output directory

Comment: @mforbes Current versions do support `output-directory` as well as `aux-directory`.

Comment: @Herbert See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/official-capitalizations-of-words-from-the-tex-world