# How to use latekmk with feynmf/feynmp?

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, build-system, feynmf

### Background

The `latexmk` tool can be used to automatically process your LaTeX files enough times to generate the output.  As discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30350/use-miktex-option-through-latexmk/31252#31252) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11710/specify-output-directory-when-using-latexmk), `latexmk` now supports setting `out_dir` which passes the `-output-directory` to `pdflatex` and places build products in this alternate location.  Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to use `latexmk` with `feynmp`.

## Question

How can I configure `latexmk` to call `mpost` for processing Feynman diagrams generated by `feynmp`?  Especially using the new `out_dir` configuration?

### Partial Answer 1

One can try to add a custom rule to the `latexmkrc` file like

```
add_cus_dep('mp', '1', 0, 'mpost');
sub mpost {
    system("mpost $_[0]");
}
```

but this fails in three ways: 1) if there are multiple images, then the extensions `.1` changes and it is not clear how to specify all the dependences. 2) I don't know how to tell `latexmk` that `pdflatex` needs to be run again after the figure is generated. 3) Even if `out_dir` is specified, `latexmk` still runs the `mpost` command in the source directory, thereby missing the generated `.mp` files.

### Partial Answer 2

As suggested [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22611/6903), one can use the `-shell-escape` option of `pdflatex` to allow the figures to be processed by the call to `pdflatex`.  Unfortunately, the call to `mpost` still takes place in the top-level directory.  Is there some way of using `-output-directory` to ensure that shell commands are executed in the appropriate place?

Here is a MWE demonstrating this second attempt:

#### `latexmkrc`

```
mkdir _build;
$out_dir = '_build';
$pdflatex="pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S";
```

#### `tst.tex`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\makeatletter
\show\endfmffile
\preto{\endfmffile}{\let\the@fmffile\thefmffile}
\appto{\endfmffile}{
  \ifnum\pdfshellescape=\@ne
    \immediate\write18{mpost \the@fmffile}%
  \else
    \message{
      Run pdf(la)tex with -shell-escape to generate feynmp diagrams}
  \fi
  \let\the@fmffile\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{title}
  \begin{fmfgraph}(40,25) 
    \fmfleft{i1,i2} 
    \fmfright{o1,o2} 
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1} 
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2} 
    \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
  \end{fmfgraph} 
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `mpost` ignores the `--output-directory` option.

Comment: @egreg This works `\write18{cd _build;mpost \the@fmffile}`.  Is there any way to get the argument to `--output-directory` programatically?

Comment: Not that I know. You can try using `"\def\outdir{_build}\input{%S}"` instead of `%S` (possibly escaping backslashes and braces) and saying `\write18{cd \outdir;mpost \the@fmffile}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an update to `latexmk`, v. 4.30a, that solves some problems with using the `-output-directory` option.  I'd recommend upgrading.

Here's a solution that works with v. 4.30a of `latexmk`:

```
$out_dir = 'output';
add_cus_dep('mp', '1', 0, 'mpost');
sub mpost {
    my $file = $_[0];
    my ($name, $path) =  fileparse( $file );
    pushd( $path );
    my $return = system "mpost $name" ;
    popd();
    return $return;
}
```

which is to be put in a `latexmkrc` file.

The above code solves the problem of persuading `mpost` to put its output files in the appropriate directory.  The new version of `latexmk` solves the other problem that on a first run, when the `.1` file does not exist, `latexmk` needed to detect the missing file condition and run `mpost`.

As far as I can tell, it does not cause a problem that if there are multiple images, `mpost` generates files with extensions like `.NNN`, where `NNN` is an integer.  In this situation, there is still a file with extension `.1`, and this is sufficient to trigger the correct use of `mpost`.