# Using Latexmk with mpost

Tags: latexmk, metapost

Is it possible to tell `latexmk` to execute `mpost paper.mp` after each compilation run if `paper.mp` has changed?

I tried to create a custom `latexmkrc` rule:

```
add_cus_dep('mp', '1', 0, 'mpost');
sub mpost {
 system "mpost $name" ;
 popd();
 return 0;
}
```

But this does not seem to work

Comment: This code is copied from part of the answer to another question, at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37350/8495, but some lines which are essential to make the code work are missing.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
add_cus_dep('mp', '1', 0, 'mpost');
sub mpost {
 return system("mpost $_[0].mp");
}
```

See [answer to question on latexmk and feynmp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37350/8495) for a more complete solution.