# latexmk cannot create document with mpost

Tags: latexmk

I use latexmk 4.77.
The following is my .latexmkrc file

```
$pdf_mode = 4;# specifies creation of pdf via lualatex 
$bibtex_use = "2";# to configure bibtex 

$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1;
push @generated_exts, "lol";
$clean_ext .= " %R.synctex.gz";


# graphics by metapost 
add_cus_dep('mp', 'mps', 0, 'mpost');


# sub mpost {
#     #return system("mptopdf $_[0].mp");
#     return system("mpost $_[0].mp");
# }

# metapost rule from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37134
#add_cus_dep('mp', '1', 0, 'mpost');
sub mpost {
  my $file = $_[0];
  my ($name, $path) = fileparse($file);
  pushd($path);
  my $return = system("mpost $name");
  popd();
  return $return;
}
```

In my mp file i configured

```
prologues := 2;
outputtemplate := "%j.mps";
```

so that really an mps file is created.
In a tex file i just included the mps with \includegraphics,
but this is immaterial in this context.

The behavior of `latexmk` is quite strange:
Running `latexmk` directly complains about missing graphic file.
But then if i run `latexmk -pvc` and command scrollmode and interrupt,
at the end, the files are compiled correctly.

I also tried `add_cus_dep('mp', '1', 1, 'mpost');`, no change.
What am I doing wrong?
Is possibly a general problem that latexmk cannot compile in situations
where before the first latex run some files must be generated already???

This would be a considerable gap since this applies to various kinds of graphics.

Comment: In the meantime i found out that also graphics created from xfig dont work.
I used the config given in latexmk documentation. 

Maybe something changed since this has been written. 
I suspect, that formerly, the rules were applied before tex was converted (which is necessary for graphics), whereas now only after the first latex run this is done. 
This behavior is only appropriate for bibliographies, indices and that like. 
Maybe this is due to an optimization based on the fls file.

Comment: I see also another possible fix: what if the package graphicx has a parameter 
treatment of missing file: either warning or error. 
If set to warning, the problem is also resolved. 
I think even better because then only graphics are created which are really needed.

Comment: In my examples, graphics from both mpost and xfig work.  So you first need to show the full contents of a minimal tex file and mp file, so we can try your example for ourselves.

Comment: The error message about the missing graphics file is expected on a first run: The message is from lualatex.  Just respond to the message with 'r' followed by return. Latexmk has no way of knowing what files are needed until after the first run of *latex. After the first run, latexmk finds out about the missing file(s), and creates them.

Comment: OT but (a) I'd strongly recommend that you get everything working "by hand" before trying to automate it (hey, but maybe you have..)  and (b) since you are using `lualatex` then you have an option of including your MP graphics in line with `luamplib` which is about 20,000 times easier than all this.

Comment: @John Collins: aaah, is see: well my expectation was that  latexmk runs through without user interaction. but you say, it is considered normal, that the user enters 'r'. 
Also 's' works. But i consider this not completely automatic compilation as I would expect. 

Could one modify latexmk in a way that it succeeds without user interaction? This would be important if used in an automatic build process.

Comment: @thurston: yes, manually first using mpost and then lualatex works of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a stolen answer:
John Collins gave the decisive hint:

in .latexmkrc insert
`set_tex_cmds('-interaction=nonstopmode %O %S');`

If a graphic file is not yet present,
then a warning is given and the file is created.
In the next latex run, all is ok.

There is nevertheless one special point with metapost:
use

```
mpost -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder -s prologues=2
```

The prologue will cause creation of an mps file.
I found that when including with `\includegraphics`,
the ending must be given.

That way also other graphic files seem to work.
I tried with xfig files, works fine.