# `latexmk`can include files created during the `latexmk` run, except with `lstinputlistings`

Tags: luatex, listings, latexmk

My latex file looks roughly like this:

```
...
\usepackage{listings}
...
\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}
...
```

and the file `F4_01fig2dev.ptx` is to be created.
In fact I want to build with `latexmk`.
Normally the technique is, to make `latexmk` run a latex processor
in `scrollmode` finding out the missing files,
create the missing files with additional rules
and then rerun the latex processor.

If I embed the file with `\input{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}`
or with `\includegraphics` (using the graphicx package) or
with `\import` (using the import package),
the usual technique with `latexmk` works.

It does not work with `\lstinputlisting`.
Originally, I told here that the reason is that
for some reason `\lstinputlisting` does not respect `scrollmode`,
but this is not the difference.
I don't want to make another wrong suspicion,
but i observed that the FLS files don't include the file to be included in any case, so no difference.
But the log file is a bit different:

```
! Package Listings Error: File `F4_01fig2dev(.ptx)' not found.
```

for the `listings` package versus

```
! LaTeX Error: File `F4_01fig2dev.ptx' not found.
```

for the other kinds of inclusions.
Maybe `latexmk` does not recognize the ending that way.
I must say, I find `listings` package more precise.

Ok, now either `latexmk` changes or `listings` package changes
or I do some workaround.

I thought of conditional code, bypassing if the file does not exist.
Any other thoughts?

As cabohah suggested, I shall add my `.latexmkrc` file.
I will post in full length,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# to create pdf via lualatex 
#$pdflatex = 'lualatex -file-line-error %O %S';

# PDF-generating modes are:
# 1: pdflatex, as specified by $pdflatex variable (still largely in use)
# 2: postscript conversion, as specified by the $ps2pdf variable (useless)
# 3: dvi conversion, as specified by the $dvipdf variable (useless)
# 4: lualatex, as specified by the $lualatex variable (best)
# 5: xelatex, as specified by the $xelatex variable (second best)
$pdf_mode = 4;# specifies creation of pdf via lualatex 

# If additional parameters must be passed to lualatex 
#'svg' package.
# It converts raw SVG files to the PDF+PDF_TEX combo using InkScape.
# $lualatex = "lualatex --shell-escape";

# note that -recorder is implicitly added 
$latex2pdfOptions = "-interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -shell-escape";
$lualatex = "lualatex $latex2pdfOptions %O %S";

#$postscript_mode = $dvi_mode = 0;

# to configure bibtex 
$bibtex_use=2;

# this cannot be done according to the according latex maven plugin, 
# because the according parameter maxNumReRunsLatex may be set to -1 
# which signifies an infinite number of runs. 
$max_repeat=30;

# default are tex and eps, but could also be pdf and ptx and mps
# Currently, all those files are given with explicit endings, 
# so no extensions to be added. 
#add_input_ext('');

# It is what it seems to be: clean inludes what was generated by cus 
$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1;
$cleanup_includes_generated = 1;

#$makeindex = 'makeindex %O -o %D %S'; # the default

# TBD: clarify: xdv and dvi seem to be internal. 
# maybe missing other extensions in conjunction with synctex
$clean_ext .= " %R.synctex.gz";

# bbl does not work
#@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'lol', 'bbl', 'glo', 'ist') 
#print "Hello!"
#foreach (@generated_exts) {
#print "Generated exts: $_\n";
#}
#print "clean_ext\n";
# Here @generated_exts is ('aux', 'fls', 'log', # generated by latex already
# 'toc', 'lof', 'lot', 'out', # generated by latex conditionally 
# 'idx', 'ind', 'blg', 'ilg', # concerning indices 
# # strange enough: nothing for bibtex 
# 'xdv', 'bcf'

# extensions ext to be deleted by latexmk -c 
# Note that the file names are %R.ext. 
# this may cause problems with extensions containing a dot. 
# Also this is not general enough 
# if the generated file deviates from %R by more than an extension. 
# In this case, use $clean_ext$
# Here, $clean_ext is empty. 
# list of listings, whereas lof and lot are already present. 
push @generated_exts, "lol";
push @generated_exts, "dvi", "xdv";
# for beamer class 
push @generated_exts, "nav", "snm", "vrb";

# why are .ist and xdy not under generated_exts? 
# note that currently, either %R or what is present is the extension only! 
# this does not make sense very much. 
# $clean_ext .= " stateMachine.log"; does not work, because stateMachine.log is the extension! 

# should be under indexing 
$clean_ext .= " %R.ist %R.xdy %R-*.ind %R-*.idx %R-*.ilg %R-*.ind";


add_cus_dep('fig', 'ptx', 0, 'fig2dev');
sub fig2dev {
  $file = $_[0];
  print("$file");
  rdb_add_generated("$file.eps", "$file.pdf", "$file.ptx");
  my $GenOptions = "";
  my $PtxOptions = "";
  my $PdfEpsOptions = "";
  print("create from $file.fig");
  rdb_add_generated("$file.ptx", "$file.pdf", "$file.eps");
  #fig2dev -L pstex    <fig2devGenOptions> <fig2devPdfEpsOptions>        xxx.fig xxx.eps   
  #fig2dev -L pdftex   <fig2devGenOptions> <fig2devPdfEpsOptions>        xxx.fig xxx.pdf   
  #fig2dev -L pdftex_t <fig2devGenOptions> <fig2devPtxOptions>    -p xxx xxx.fig xxx.ptx

  my $ret1 = system("fig2dev -L  pstex   $GenOptions $PdfEpsOptions       $file.fig $file.eps");
  my $ret2 = system("fig2dev -L pdftex   $GenOptions $PdfEpsOptions       $file.fig $file.pdf");
  my $ret3 = system("fig2dev -L pdftex_t $GenOptions $PtxOptions -p $file $file.fig $file.ptx");


  return ($ret1 or $ret2 or $ret3);
}

add_cus_dep('gp', 'ptx', 0, 'gnuplot');
sub gnuplot {
  $file = $_[0];
  print("create from $file.gp");
  rdb_add_generated("$file.ptx", "$file.pdf", "$file.eps");
  my $nuplotOptions = "";
  my $ret1 = system("gnuplot -e \"set terminal cairolatex pdf $gnuplotOptions;\
            set output '$file.ptx';\
            load '$file.gp'\"");
  # my $ret2 = system("gnuplot -e \"set terminal cairolatex eps $gnuplotOptions;\
  #           set output '$file.ptx';\
  #           load '$file.gp'\"");
  return $ret;
}

# metapost rule from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37134
#add_cus_dep('mp', 'mps', 0, 'mpost');
add_cus_dep('mp', 'mps', 0, 'mpost');
sub mpost {
  my $file = $_[0];
  print("create from $file.mp");
  rdb_add_generated("$file.mps", "$file.fls", "$file.log");
  my ($name, $path) = fileparse($file);
  pushd($path);
  my $return = system("mpost -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder -s prologues=2 -s 'outputtemplate=\"%j.mps\"' $name");
  popd();
  return $return;
}


add_cus_dep('svg', 'ptx', 0, 'inkscape');
sub inkscape {
  my $file = $_[0];
  print("create from $file.svg");
  rdb_add_generated("$file.ptx", "$file.pdf");
  my $ret1 = system("inkscape -D --export-filename=$file.pdf --export-latex $file.svg ");
  #my $ret2 = system("inkscape -D --export-filename=$file.eps --export-latex $file.svg ");
  #use File::Copy;
  # This works only for pdf, not for eps. 
  #unlink($file.pdf_tex) or die "cannot unlink $file.pdf_tex";
  rename("$file.pdf_tex", "$file.ptx");# or die "cannot move $file.pdf_tex";
  return $ret1;# or $ret2;
}


# graphics for xfig (not appropriate for mixed tex/pdf)

# add_cus_dep('fig', 'pdf', 0, 'fig2pdf');

# sub fig2pdf {
# system( "fig2dev -Lpdf \"$_[0].fig\" \"$_[0].pdf\"" );
# }


# use splitindex 
$makeindex = 'internal splitindex';

sub splitindex {
   # Use splitindex instead of makeindex.
   # The splitindex programe starts from an .idx file, makes a set of
   #   other .idx files for separate indexes, and then runs makeindex to
   #   make corresponding .ind files.
   # However, it is possible that the document uses the splitindex
   #   package, but in a way compatible with the standard methods
   #   compatible with makeindex, i.e., with a single index and with the
   #   use of the \printindex command.
   #   Then we need to invoke makeindex.
   # In addition, latexmk assumes that makeindex or its replacement makes
   #   an .ind file from an .idx file, and latexmk gives an error if it
   #   doesn't exist, we need to make an .ind file.
   # Both problems are solved by running makeindex and then splitindex.
   # Note: errors are returned by makeindex and splitindex for things
   #   like a missing input file.  No error is returned for lines in an
   #   input file that are in an incorrect format; they are simply
   #   ignored.  So no problem is caused by lines in the .idx file
   #   that are generated by splitindex in a format incompatible with
   #   makeindex.
   my $ret1 = system( "makeindex", $$Psource );
   my $ret2 = system( "splitindex", $$Psource );
   return $ret1 || $ret2;
}


add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
push @generated_exts, "ist"; # index stylefile created by the glossaries package 

#$clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";# TBD: clarify: better in @generated_exts? 

sub makeglossaries {
     my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
     my @args = ( "-q", "-d", $path, $base_name );
     if ($silent) { unshift @args, "-q"; }
     return system "makeglossaries", "-d", $path, $base_name; 
}

sub run_makeglossaries {
    my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] ); #handle -outdir param by splitting path and file, ...
    pushd $path; # ... cd-ing into folder first, then running makeglossaries ...

    if ( $silent ) {
        # system "makeglossaries -q '$base_name'"; #unix
        system "makeglossaries", "-q", "$base_name"; #windows
    }
    else {
        # system "makeglossaries '$base_name'"; #unix
        system "makeglossaries", "$base_name"; #windows
    };

    popd; # ... and cd-ing back again
}


# !!! ONLY WORKS WITH VERSION 4.54 or higher of latexmk
#TBD: take into account: modified: 
#  '$_[0]'->


# #############
# # makeindex #
# #############
# @ist = glob("*.ist");
# if (scalar(@ist) > 0) {
#         $makeindex = "makeindex -s $ist[0] %O -o %D %S";
# }


# glossaries new with bib2gls 

# push @generated_exts, 'glstex', 'glg';

# add_cus_dep('aux', 'glstex', 0, 'run_bib2gls');

# sub run_bib2gls {
#     if ( $silent ) {
#         my $ret = system "bib2gls --silent --group $_[0]";
#     } else {
#         my $ret = system "bib2gls --group $_[0]";
#     };
    
#     my ($base, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
#     if ($path && -e "$base.glstex") {
#         rename "$base.glstex", "$path$base.glstex";
#     }

#     # Analyze log file.
#     local *LOG;
#     $LOG = "$_[0].glg";
#     if (!$ret && -e $LOG) {
#         open LOG, "<$LOG";
#       while (<LOG>) {
#             if (/^Reading (.*\.bib)\s$/) {
#               rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $1 );
#           }
#       }
#   close LOG;
#     }
#     return $ret;
# }





$pythontex = 'pythontexW %R';#'pythontexW %O %R';
push @generated_exts, "pytxcode", "plg";
push @generated_exts, "depytx", "dplg";

$clean_ext .= " pythontex-files-%R/* pythontex-files-%R";
#$extra_rule_spec{'pythontex'}  = [ 'internal', '', 'mypythontex', "%Y%R.pytxcode", "%Ypythontex-files-%R/%R.pytxmcr", "%R", 1 ];
$extra_rule_spec{'pythontex'} = [ 'internal', '', 'mypythontex', "%R.pytxcode", "pythontex-files-%R/%R.pytxmcr", "%R", 1 ];

sub mypythontex {
   my $result_dir = $aux_dir1."pythontex-files-$$Pbase";
   my $ret = Run_subst( $pythontex, 2 );
   rdb_add_generated( glob "$result_dir/*" );
   #my $fh = new FileHandle $$Pdest, "r";
   open( my $fh, "<", $$Pdest );
   if ($fh) {
      print "path: $ENV{PATH}";
      while (<$fh>) {
         if ( /^%PythonTeX dependency:\s+'([^']+)';/ ) {
         print "Found pythontex dependency '$1'\n";
             rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $aux_dir1.$1 );
     }
      }
      undef $fh;
   }
   else {
       warn "mypythontex: I could not read '$$Pdest'\n",
            "  to check dependencies\n";
   }
   return $ret;
}


# for htlatex 
push @generated_exts, "4tc", "4ct", "tmp", "xref", "css", "idv", "lg";
# TBD: for -C remove also html and xhtml
# TBD: check that this plugin also removes all these extensions.. think of lg. 


# biblatex
# push @generated_exts, "run.xml";# does run.xml work? 
# $clean_ext .= " %R-blx.bib";
```

Comment: It is not a bug that listings errors if a file doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want to ignore missing files, you could use `nonstopmode` or `batchmode`. `scrollmode` explicitly should stop for missing files → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91624/277964 or TeX by Topic, Chapter 32.

Comment: @ulrike, no i never said, it is a bug that listings errors but that it does not respect scrollmode.. but this was my mistake, it does respect scrollmode. 
The problem is sth different. I corrected my post accordingly.

Comment: @cabohah: that is exactly what i did. I thought lualatex does not respect nonstopmode 
in conjunction with listings package, but this was wrong; I corrected the post accordingly.

Comment: Patching `listings.sty` (without changing the package file itself) to show another message is easy. See my answer. But I cannot really test, if this would be the solution, because I don't know your complete build process and so don't know, how the building of the missing file is triggered and how it would be created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command in `functional` to judge file if exist.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage{listings}
\NewDocumentCommand{\LstIfExistInputListing}{m}{\fileIfExistT{#1}{\lstinputlisting{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\fileIfExistT{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}{\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}}
or
\LstIfExistInputListing{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: works formally, but does not work in the context of latexmk.
As the file does not exist, the document is empty.
But as no dependency on the ptx file exists, latexmk does not trigger the rule to create it.

Comment: @user2609605 you could typeset something and use input or whatever if the file doesn't exist. (I doubt that an additional package is needed the standard IfFileExists should be enough).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I could use 
\fileIfExistT{xxx.ptx}{\lstinputlisting{xxxptx}}{\input{xxx.ptx}}. 
So still I need the package functional.

Comment: I wonder how the package listings manages to ignore the `-interaction` flag. 
How is this possible??? Could this occur in other places too?

Comment: @user2609605 stopping if a file is not found is normal behaviour. It also stops with `\input` in standard LaTeX. If \input works differently for you you are using something that redefines \input.

Comment: @Ulrike, no i did with nonstopmode, then it is not normal. 
But I made a mistake: listings does respect nonstopmode. I corrected my post.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to change the `F4_01fig2dev(.ptx)` in the error message to `F4_01fig2dev.ptx`,you can do this using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NewLine}{^^J}%
\xpatchcmd{\lst@MissingFileError}
  {`#1(.#2)' not found.}
  {`#1.#2' not found.\NewLine}
  {%
    \typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space done.}%
  }{%
   \typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space failed.}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test
\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}
\end{document}
```

Here this results in the error message:

> ```
> ! Package Listings Error: File `F4_01fig2dev.ptx' not found.
> Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: ptx)
> ```

If needed you could also replace "Package Listings" by "LaTeX":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NewLine}{^^J}%
\xpatchcmd{\lst@MissingFileError}
  {Package Listings Error: File `#1(.#2)' not found.}
  {LaTeX Error: File `#1.#2' not found.\NewLine}{%
    \typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space done.}%
  }{%
    \typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space failed.}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test
\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: File `F4_01fig2dev.ptx' not found.
> Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: ptx)
> ```

In both cases, the default extension is still shown in the error message. But because of the patch, the space token before `or` is missing. If this is important, you would have to replace the whole message, not only the first line.

Disclaimer: I don't know if an how `latexmk` triggers to one of these messages, because the corresponding parts of your `latexmk` configuration are missing in your question, so I cannot test it.

Comment: wow! the second variant works fine! (by the way, the first does not). 
I will add the `.latexmkrc` as you suggested. 
Maybe we can even improve. 

Why is this better than my solution below? I think because one can patch at one place, 
Instead of poluting the latex document all over in each place including a listing 
as one must do with `\fileIfExistTF`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very close to what Clara suggested.
The line of code is

```
\fileIfExistTF{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}{\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}}{\input{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}}
```

In the first `lualatex` run `F4_01fig2dev.ptx` does not exist,
but `latexmk` detects the missing file through `\input{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}`
and creates it by an according rule.
In all following runs, `F4_01fig2dev.ptx`
and so `\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}` is used.

It is not really satisfactory,
because of course,
the change from `\input{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}` to `\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}`
changes the decomposition into pages causing additional `lualatex` runs.

Also it polutes the code a bit (lstinputlisting comes with a lot of parameters in my case. )

So I would maybe prefer a better solution.

Comment: The solution of cabohah is superior!